# How to set sorting route in GridView-yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I need to change sorting route in GridView,for example if it GridView load from `default/index` action,the sorting route is the same,but I need to set it as `default/sorting`.

the following GridView configuration doesn't work for me.

```
echo GridView::widget([
...// other configuration
'sorter'            =>  [
    'class' =>  'yii\widgets\LinkSorter',
    'sort'  =>  new yii\data\Sort(['route' => 'default/sorting'])
],
...// other configuration
]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the sorting route through `$dataProvider`.

```
$dataProvider->sort->route = 'posts/default/sorting';

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

    ...
]);
```

Note that for correct generated urls the route must be fully specified, including module ids (if any).

**Official documentation:**

- [yii\data\BaseDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider.html) [$sort](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider.html#$sort-detail)
- [yii\base\Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html) [$route](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#$route-detail)